# bash only email if occurrence since last alert

Tags: bash, scripting, grep

I'm monitoring a log file for a specific word and using tac to output the 5 lines before and after it

```
#!/bin/bash
tac /var/log/syslog |grep -m1 -A5 -B5 'WORD' | tac >> /tmp/systemp
mailx email commands  
rm /tmp/systemp
```

and I've setup a cron to run every 5 minutes however as expected I receive duplicate alert emails, how do I make it send an email for the last occurrence and not again until the next one?

ie

```
Feb 27 15:05:39 WORD (email)
Cron runs again after 5 minutes
Feb 27 15:05:39 WORD (don't email)
Cron runs again after 5 minutes 
Feb 27 15:35:39 WORD (email)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should only search trough last 5 min of data:

```
data5m=$(awk '$0>=from' from="$(date +"%b %e %H:%M:%S" -d -5min)" /var/log/syslog)
```

Then you can grep from this data:

```
grep -m1 -C5 'WORD' <<< "$data5m"
```

---

Update:

```
awk '$0>=from' from="$(date +"%b %e %H:%M:%S" -d -5min)" /var/log/syslog | grep -m1 -C5 'WORD'
```

Or all in one `awk`

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} /pattern/ && $0>=from {f=NR} END {for (i=f-5;i<=f+5;i++) print a[i]}' from="$(date +"%b %e %H:%M:%S" -d -5min)" /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: cool embedded `date`, but can't you just pipe `awk` output to `grep`?

Comment: @shellter, yes you can.  You can even do all with `awk`, but it get some more complicated if you like 5 hit before and 5 hit after pattern.  You can also change `-A5` and `-B5` with `-C5`, see my update.

Comment: Thanks Jotne one problem is that it emails me even if there has been no occurrence of the word ie a blank email.

Comment: @Lurch This can simple be solved by testing if there is no data and then skip the email command.

Comment: @Jotne how would I do this as if tried using 'if -eq' but with limited success.