# Extract data from log

Tags: shell, unix, awk, scripting, sh

I have logs in format

```
##<01-Mar-2015 03:48:18 o'clock GMT> <info> 
##<01-Mar-2015 03:48:20 o'clock GMT> <info>
##<01-Mar-2015 03:48:30 o'clock GMT> <info>
##<01-Mar-2015 03:48:39 o'clock GMT> <info>
```

I got to write shell script to extract data of last 5 minutes from the last recorded data in the log file and then search a string in it.I am new to shell script , I used grep command but its of no use.Can anyone help me here.
I tried the below script

```
#!/bin/bash

H=1  ## Hours
LOGFILE=/path/to/logfile.txt

X=$(( H * 60 * 60 )) ## Hours converted to seconds

function get_ts {
DATE="${1%%\]*}"; DATE="${DATE##*\[}"; DATE=${DATE/:/ };                 DATE=${DATE//\// }
TS=$(date -d "$DATE" '+%s')
}

get_ts "$(tail -n 1 "$LOGFILE")"
LAST=$TS

while read -r LINE; do
get_ts "$LINE"
(( (LAST - TS) <= X )) && echo "$LINE"
done < "$LOGFILE"
```

and on running it get the below error 
get_ts: DATE=${DATE/:/ }: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've tried already and some sample input with the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 0):

IF you use `awk`, you can use  `date` to get data for example last `5` minutes like this:

```
awk '$0>=from' from="$(date +"##<%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S" -d -5min)" logile
```

PS, you need the  `date` command to match your format.

Comment: Possible duplicate answer of http://stackoverflow.com/a/28815704/2088135 :)

Comment: It is giving me the whole log file

Comment: @Angel1403 I just did change the  `date` format some.  It needs to be 100% correct, or else you get all. Run this `date +"##<%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"` and see if its match the start of the line.

Comment: @TomFenech I know, but it would be better to mark question as duplicate :)

Comment: Well, what are you waiting for then?!

Comment: @TomFenech A cup of coffee and nice weather.

Comment: Is awk smart enough to compare the month names properly? And indeed recognize that they have a bigger impact than the day. I'd expect this to go haywire if there are events from Feb 28th still in the logfile.

Comment: @Wintermute That I can not answer, but I have used this with other logfiles, like syslog, and there it works perfectly. But, yes I see that the way date is formatted may impact on the result.

Comment: I corrected the date format.it still gives me the whole log file

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse the date into seconds since epoch and compare that with the system time:

```
TZ=GMT awk -F '[#<> :-]+' 'BEGIN { split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", mnames, ","); for(i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) m[mnames[i]] = i } mktime($4 " " m[$3] " " $2 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7) + 300 >= systime()' filename
```

The `-F '[#<> :-]+'` is to split the date into individual parts, so that `$2` is the day, `$3` the month, `$4` the year, and so forth. Then the code works as follows:

```
BEGIN {
  # build a mapping from month name to number (to use in mktime)
  split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec", mnames, ",")
  for(i = 1; i <= 12; ++i) m[mnames[i]] = i
}

# build a numerically comparable timestamp from the split date, and
# select all lines whose timestamp is not more than 300 seconds behind
# the system time.
mktime($4 " " m[$3] " " $2 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7) + 300 >= systime()
```

Setting the `TZ` environment variable to `GMT` (with `TZ=GMT` before the awk call) will make `mktime` interpret the time stamps as GMT.